# How do I propagate an exception thrown by croak in forked child to parent/foreground process?

Tags: perl, exception, fork

Throwing an exception via `croak` in a forked child process seems to print the error as a background process would. That is, it clobbers the shell prompt.

If I `die` instead of `croak`, the the error message pops up as a foreground process. I've trying to find out why that is in the `Carp` documentation without any luck.

Here's what I mean. The `croak` version:

```
$ perl Wrapper.pm
$ error: ... does not exist at Wrapper.pm line 624
```

The `die` version:

```
$ perl Wrapper.pm
error: ... does not exist at Wrapper.pm line 515.
```

I tried trapping the `fork` and printing `$@` to STDERR and exiting, but that didn't have an effect. Any ideas? I'd like to be able to use `croak` in this particular case.

Although my code is quite a bit more convoluted, here is how you can reproduce this behavior:

```
$ perl -MCarp -e 'unless (fork) {croak "child"}'
$ child at -e line 1
  <- cursor blinking here. Pressing enter gives me a new prompt:
$

$ perl -e 'unless (fork) {die "child"}'
child at -e line 1.
$
```

**Solved:** cjm [got it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947727/how-do-i-propagate-an-exception-thrown-by-croak-in-forked-child-to-parent-foregro/2947869#2947869):

```
$ perl -e '$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {sleep 1}; unless (fork) {die "child"}'
$ child at -e line 1.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm skeptical that a `die` call in a child process makes the error message pop up to the parent, or that either `die` or `croak` messages have anything to do with the shell prompt. Can you post a small snippet of code that exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's just a timing issue.  The `die` version is slightly faster, so it has a better chance of outputting the error message before the shell can print the next prompt.  When I try running your examples, the `croak` version usually gets printed after the prompt, but occasionally it comes before the prompt.  The `die` version pretty consistently comes before the prompt.